# How to get Id of last persisted entity using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I am looking a smart and easily readable way to get the id of a persisted entity using `JPA`. The id is an `Integer`.

One could think of the following solutions:

1. Without using `GeneratedValue` strategy. This requires looking for a free id before persisting, then putting it into the entity to be persisted: cumbersome, but works.
2. With a `GeneratedValue` strategy. The persistence provider will take care of the id generation. This looks smarter, but how to get the id?

See below for solution 2

```
MyEntity en = new MyEntity();
en.setName("My name");
em.persist(en);
System.out.println(en.getId());
```

This prints a null id!

Any suggestions? I am using MySql, EclipseLink, but need a portable solution.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

persist is not guaranteed to generate the ID. The ID is guaranteed to be generated at flush time only. So if you really need the ID before the transaction ends (and the entity manager is thus flushed), call flush() explicitely to get the ID:

```
MyEntity en = new MyEntity();
en.setName("My name");
em.persist(en);
em.flush();
System.out.println(en.getId());
```

Comment: @JB Nizet, how can I get id before `persist()` method? I am looking forward it because of I would like change custom id format?

Comment: @CycDemo: you can't, unless you generate it by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Where is the source of the statement "persist is not guaranteed to generate the ID"? In the JPS Spec (JSR ) I read the following two statements (Chapter 3.2):
- A managed entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity
- The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as follows: If X is a new entity, it becomes managed. ... *If I interpret that word by word, I would say that the spec demands that the Id is set after calling persist()*. That is also the behaviour of Hibernate.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-makingpersistent

Comment: @JBNizet Wow that was a quick answer :-). However I do not completely agree that this link is the definitive answer. It references the Hibernate documentation. Hibernate seems to make a difference between persist() and save(). JPA does not provide this difference, so the semantics must not necessarily be the same. And if I read the JSR-338 I would say it demands that Id is set after calling persist().

Comment: The spec also says that the PostPersist(), in which the ID is available, may only be called at flush time. The javadoc of PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier() also says that a generated id is not guaranteed to the database insert has occurred. JPA doesn't have a save() method, so obviously, it can't make a distinction between save() and persist().

Comment: @JBNizet The fact that EclipseLink is the reference implementation gives you right, of course. But Hibernate actually behaves different than EclipseLink. Hibernate actually performs an SQL insert when calling persist() and not when calling flush()/commit() in the case of the IdentityGenerationStrategy defining that the DB generates the Id. So I would guess Hibernate maps the JPA-persist() to the Hibernate-save().

Comment: This works only with em.persist(en), but not with em.merge(en). Using merge it returns null.