# Java JPA get id of last persisted entity issue

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have read the article here but I cannot get fix my problem [How to get Id of last persisted entity using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649515/how-to-get-id-of-last-persisted-entity-using-jpa)

I cannot get the last auto incremented primary key of the student

This is from the Servlet class

```
if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {
            student.setName(name);
            student.setAddress(address);


            int last = studentDAO.addStudent(student);
            request.setAttribute("last", last);
            request.setAttribute("student", student);

        }
```

This is from the session bean:

```
public int addStudent(Student student) {
        em.persist(student);

        em.flush();

        System.out.println(student.getStudentID());
        return student.getStudentID();
    }
```

I just used sout to test and see if I got the `ID` but it always outputs `0` every time I add a `student`. I cannot get the last generated `id`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDITED:
My Student Class:**

package model;

import javax.persistence.*;

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="Student.getAll", query="Select e from Student e")})
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column
    private int studentID;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String address;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public Student(int studentID, String name, String address) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Student(){}
}
```

--**Solved! Answered by Peter, Thank you!**

Comment: Can you please post your student class here ?

Comment: Also print the stacktrace of the exception please (an exception should occur, except you are doing something elementary wrong (like printing the wrong variable)).

Comment: I have added the Student Class entity.

Comment: @Andrei Noted. I'm kinda new here and I had trouble finding an accept answer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id is incremented in your db? Maybe you forgot @GeneratedValue annotation above your id definition.
Check this: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: Stupid mistake. I have forgetted to add  @GeneratedValue to the ID. Thank you Peter!!