# How to get the ID (PRIMARY KEY) from an entity object after commit transaction?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

After I persist an object and commit like this:

```
        Version version = new Version();
        version.setVersion(getNext(this.version));
        version.setProjectID(projectID);
        em.persist(version);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I want to get the ID(Primary Key) by this code line:

`Object id = factory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(version);`

I can get the `Version` and `ProjectID` but the `ID` is **null**. The ID is auto generated but still return null. I tried to implement `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` in my entity class but nothing change. Any solution for me?

**EDIT WITH MORE CODE**

Version Entity: this is using an EmbededId

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQuery(name="Version.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM Version v")
    @Table(name="Version")
    public class Version implements Serializable {    

    @EmbeddedId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private VersionPK id;

    @Column(name="Version")
    private String version;

    @Column(name="ProjectID")
    private int projectID;
```

Embeddable class:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class VersionPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    public VersionPK() {
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but you might have a look at the `@id` annotation from JPA2. Maybe that solves your problem.

Comment: maybe showing people your actual class may help?

Comment: I think the problem is because that entity object cannot get the auto generate ID from database. Method `version.getId()` always return null but `version.getVersion` and `version.getProjectID` is working well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `flush()` after commiting to be able to get the `id`:

```
em.persist(version);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.flush();
```

Then just use getter to have the id:

```
Object id = version.getId();//getId() is the getter of the id in your entity.
```

[See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649515/how-to-get-id-of-last-persisted-entity-using-jpa).

Comment: flush() after commit is pointless because it will throw a TransactionRequiredException if no transaction is active, as per the javadoc.

Comment: In this case it'will be safer to ensure that your transaction is not `null`

Comment: what has null got to do with it? if you commit the txn then there is no transaction, aka your code

Comment: That's why you have to test that your transaction is not null before committing.

Comment: I said calling flush AFTER commit is wrong. flush is for use _within_ a transaction

Comment: I tried flush after persist and get the ID back but it still null. And I'm sure my transaction is not null.